# Merge two arrays efficiently - one sorted, another unsorted

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I am working on a problem that has a sorted array of n elements followed by an unsorted array of length

1. O(logn)
2. O(sqrt(n))

How to sort the entire list most efficiently? Which sorting should I use in the above two cases?

Comment: Can we use the info O(logn) in the first case? Can we use any data structure and sort it more efficiently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since inserting a single element into array and keeping it sorted is `O(n)`, you cannot get better then that.

Thus, for both cases - sorting the smaller array and then using `merge(part1,part2)` will be `O(n)`, and thus optimal in terms of asymptotic complexity.

- sorting the smaller array: `O(logn*loglog(n))`, or `O(sqrt(n)*log(sqrt(n))` respectively of the cases.
- `merge(part1,part2)`: `O(n+logn)` or `O(n+sqrt(n))`, which is `O(n)`<sup>1</sup> anyway.

So, the **total complexity of both cases is `O(n)`**, which is optimal for this problem.

---

(1) It is true because, `log(n)^k` is asymptotically smaller then `n^m` for each `k>0,m>0`, and specifically for `k=1, m=1/2`.

Proof is based on taking logs on both sides:

```
log (log(n)^k) <? log(n^m) <=>
k*log(log(n)) <? m*log(n)
```

The last is obviously true (for large `n` and constant `k,m>0`), and thus the claim is true.

From this we can conclude that `sqrt(n)*log(n) < sqrt(n) * n^1/2 = n`, and thus it is indeed `O(n)`.

Comment: Your logic is right, just that it was not obvious that `O(sqrt(N)*log(N)) < O(N)`

Comment: @salva: I'll clarify, but basically `log(n)^k` is asymptotically smaller then `n^m` for each `k,m`, and specifically for `k=1,m=1/2`.

Comment: @salva: I added a detailed explanation as a footnote for this claim.

Answer (score 5):

You could simply sort the unsorted array and then do a [merge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) (as in the [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) algorithm) on those 2 sorted arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Easy, sort the second part and merge it with the first (same as **merge** sort). The merging step of two sorted subarrays is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `part1` and `part2` sizes r O(log n) and O(sqrt(n)) respectively. So, if you choose one element from `part2` and find the position in `part1` in log(log n) by using binary search , and do so recursively until elements of `part2` are not empty, total running time becomes  **O(sqrt(n) log(log n)**).

Comment: Finding the location of the element (from part2) in part1 by binary search will take logn. But to place the element in its proper position in part1 will take linear time(O(n)). Here the sorted array in part 1 has n elements. There are two problems. The unsorted array length in the first problem is logn and in the second problem is sqrt(n).