# sort on arrays in O(n+mlogm) time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

I was doing some algorithm things. There are two arrays, array A with length n has been sorted in ascending order while array B with length m is not. The question asks us to produce an array where m+n integers are sorted in ascending order. And it should terminates in o(n+mlogm) time. What I think is to perform merge sort on B first and it may take o(mlogm) time. Then perform merge sort on A and B but clearly it takes more time. Are there any other solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two arrays efficiently - one sorted, another unsorted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13862701/merge-two-arrays-efficiently-one-sorted-another-unsorted)

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the first step is sorting of the second array in O(mlogm).

But the second step is simple merging of sorted arrays that takes O(n + m)

(merging is equal to Merge phase of mergesort. [Arbitrary example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958169/how-to-merge-two-sorted-arrays-into-a-sorted-array))

So overall complexity is O(mlogm + m + n) = O(mlogm + n)

Comment: seems right, complexity would be O(n + m + mlogm) -> O(n + mlogm)